# How to play sound with package audioplayers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-player

I'm doing course on flutter. I was trying to play sound in flutter.

Sadly, I'm having below error code

Here is my complete code

```dart
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final player=AudioPlayer();
                    await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/note1.wav'));
                   },
                  child: const Text('Click Me'))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml file settings

```
dependencies:
  audioplayers: ^1.1.1

assets:
  - sounds/
```

Here is my errors:

```
****[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/sounds/note1.wav
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:258:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:75:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:101:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AudioPlayer.setSourceAsset (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:237:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:123:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      XylophoneApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:xylophone1/main.dart:16:21)
<asynchronous suspension>****
```

I just need to play sound with this audio player package.

I've changed pubspec.yaml settings and folder name "assets"
I also changed source this line to await "player.play(AssetSource('note1.wav'));"

Comment: did you rebuild the app after adding assets?

Comment: Yes but it didn't work.

Comment: try with providing full path and separate the `home`'s scaffold into another widget

Comment: Finally this suggestion works for me given by another programmer.

you have some options:

1) Rename sounds folder to assets and specify it in pubspec as

assets:

- assets/

and then call it just by name, i.e. "note1.wav"

2) Create assets folder and move sounds folder to it and specify it in pubspec as

assets:

- assets/sounds/

and then call it with folder name, i.e. "sounds/note1.wav"

Comment: Btw, don't forget to play the sound player.play(AssetSource('sounds/note1.wav'));, you don't need to set source for this.

Looks like flutter ignores resources outside of assets folder hence the error always says Unable to load asset: assets/sounds/note1.wav, but I didn't find any relevant docs for it. At least for now.

Answer (score 0):

`Audioplayers` adds `assets/` in front of your file path. This is why you got exception:

```
Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/sounds/note1.wav
```

`Audioplayers` expects you to have `assets` as a root folder for your assets. In other words,  in your `pubspec.yaml` you should have the following:

```
 assets: 
   - assets/sounds/
```

Then you put all your audio files in the `sounds` folder. There is no need to specify every file in pubspec.

Keep your player in a separate class/library for reusability and readability:

*player.dart*

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class Player {
  static play(String src) async {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    await player.play(AssetSource(src));
  }
}
```

Call it:

```
onPressed: () {
    Player.play('sounds/note1.wav');
}
```